# How are people accomplishing photo filters in iPhoneOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, imagemagick

What are people using/doing to create photo filters or photoshop like effects on iPhone OS?  Things like B&W, sepia, cross-processing, 'vintage' etc.  I see ImageMagick can probably do this with a lot of futzing around, any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageMagick was not the way, its to slow.  The solution is to access the raw byte data and modify the RGB values pixel by pixel using, among other things, 5x5 matrix transforms.  Here is a good place to start:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/11158-share-your-image-proccessing-filter-code.html

Answer (score 7):

Brad Larson's GPUImage framework will be your best Option.You can get the framework from [here](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage).

Comment: Thanks Balan, I'll look into this, this may be the new answer :)

Comment: @Shizam Read the documentation about the Framework in that GitHub Link.It would be very helpful to you:)

Answer (score 4):

Here is another option.

http://www.binpress.com/app/photo-effects-sdk-for-ios/801

Comment: Thats a pretty nice looking drop in solution as long as you're ok w/supporting 5.x only (which is really the majority case at this point anyway).